# SQL Partitioned Table - How do I Insert data that doesn't need to be partitioned into a partitioned table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, data-warehouse, partitioning

I have partitioned a fact table using the following steps:

1. Rename Fact Table ( Acts as a Backup)
2. Created two file groups based on a load id of the data ( I am processing 1000 rows for load id 1 and 1000 rows for load id 2)
3. Created A Partition function that covers the range left of values within the two loads.
4. Created corresponding Schemes for these which contains the two file groups and a [primary] file group.
5. Created the new fact table with the partitions and inserted the data back in.

This all works fine.
The problem is that I have other data that is cannot be covered by ranges, which I need to insert back into the new table. (There is no requirement to partition this data)

Could I simply do an insert into the new table for the other data? Where would that data go if I did this, ie which filegroup?

Or do I need to tell the partition function/scheme to put this other data somewhere but not in the partitioned file groups?

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Many thanks :)

Comment: which dbms are you asking about?  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: In MySQL, if you aren't going to have a million rows, why bother partitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your partitions on both ends and have a buffer for your partition function to dump data outside the range, left and right, you can assign the files to the partition function via the Partition Scheme in SQL Server.

```
File 1 - BUFFER PARTITION A
File 2 - BUFFER PARTITION AA
File 3 - PARTITION LEFT
File 4 - PARTITION RIGHT
File 5 - BUFFER PARTITION Z
File 6 - BUFFER PARTITION ZZ
```

`BUFFER PARTITION AA` and `BUFFER PARTITION Z` can handle overflow.

Then you can do useful stuff like swap out files or insert and reorder.

Comment: Hi Ross, Thanks for your response, could you please give me an example of  how I might approach this. Is this something that would be defined in both the scheme and the function? Many Thanks

Comment: Create the partition scheme to map the partition function on the files, with extra files at both ends as fan-out, however, this is standard for SQL Server and MySQL might have other partitioning techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is partitioned, it will go into one or more of the partitions you have based on your schema.  You can just do an insert, and the server will place it in the proper partition automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A partitioned table means that it is going to use the partition function to figure out where to put each row. There is no such thing as the data in  table being partitioned and not being partitioned. Maybe you should have a second table. Or you may try creating a computed column that puts all the rows that should not be partitioned be placed into a partition of its own and crate the partition function on the computed column. If you are going to use a computed column for the partition function make sure it is defined as persisted.